# UIView drawViewHierarchyInRect giving pixelated results?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm using `-drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` to draw a `view` into a `UIImage`, but it seems no matter what I do the results is always a very low resolution, because the image seems to need to be the same size as the original view?

The `UIView` is the size of the screen (in this case, 375 x 667), and the content scale factor is 2.0f.

But when I use `-drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` to draw the `view` onto the `image`, it is resized (horribly) to this resolution, even though the contents is a much higher resolution.

I'm using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` with a scale of 0.0 to create the `image`, so I assumed it should draw nicely, but no go. How do you draw the view hierarchy and not lose the detail?

Edit:
Here's some example code (from the answer below, which is giving the same result). It's giving me terribly down-scaled results when trying to draw the UIView hierarchy which includes a high res image:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, NO, 0);
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imgView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:imgView];
```

Comment: Can you paste your code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly. It takes screenshot of current `view` and puts it to new created `UIImageView`. Please check that

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, NO, 0);
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imgView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:imgView];
```

Comment: this is actually exactly what I'm doing. Running this with a UIView that includes a high res image, gives a terribly down-scaled result, as it tries to fit it into the screen resolution (without the scale), which is so much lower.

Comment: Could you please share more details? I cannot reproduce pixellate images in my machine. Maybe your experiencing that only at particular device or only simulator etc?

Comment: I'm not too sure how to explain it. I've tried on multiple devices with both iOS7 & iOS8. For exmaple, if I have a UIView with a UIImageView with a high res image in it, then use drawViewHierarchyInRect, the image is down scaled really badly. It seems like this is done to match the size of the UIView (without scaling?!), even though when it's displayed it's perfect quality. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Right now I have put enormous `image` to my `view` and run that code again and all fine. Seems like your issue somewhere in another place